# Связь БД с ListView

Tags: android

Есть у меня бд(база данных). В ней `id` записей. А есть `ListView` по нажатию на который нужно получить данные из записи бд. В `ListView` и в бд `id` разные. Как мне идентифицировать нужную мне запись?

Comment: Откуда берет данные `ListView`?

Comment: @VAndrJ Из курсора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз у вас есть список который берет данные из курсора, значит у вас есть `Adapter`. Переопределите у адаптера метод `getItemId(int position)` чтобы он возвращал реальный id по позиции:

```
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
}
```

После чего в обработчике клика по элементу списка сможете получить реальный id записи, с которой связан "кликнутый" элемент списка вызвав этот метод.

Answer (score 1):

Из вашего вопроса понятно, что у вас каша в голове, вы путаете понятия id для списка и БД, если хотите просто вывести данные из БД в список, то воспользуйтесь [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html), вот [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/111-urok-52-simplecursoradapter-primer-ispolzovanija) вполне доступный пример использования. Чтобы добавить ID в каждый пункт списка необходимо использовать Tag, это объект, который хранит в себе информацию, к примеру ID записи из БД и он не будет отображаться в списке, с помощью него и можно проводить идентификацию, вот [так](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()) его можно получить

Comment: Это хороший ответ. Только у меня нет ссылки на View

Comment: @РоманКавыршин Вы можете переопределить SimpleCursorAdapter, можете загуглить на эту тему и при создании каждого View элемента добавлять Tag с нужными значениями

Comment: У меня SimpleAdapter